# I want to build a multi-number classifier

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, mnist

I have build a mnist-digit classifier using tensorflow. Now i want to classify multiple numbers in an image using the above trained model. How can i do that?
[The images look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDEI5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to elaborate on how the numbers in the image look. MNIST is a dataset of grayscale handwritten digits so a classifier trained on that dataset can only be expected to perform well on **images that are similar to the training data** i.e. grayscale image with a single number. Otherwise the MNIST trained classifier isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

> What you describe is the **transition** **from** a pure **classifier** **to** a
>   classifier plus localization (also known as **detection**).

There are at least two general approaches to this:

1. Use a **sliding window** approach (different strides and sizes) to move over the image and hand the windows to your classifier (you can reuse your already trained model, assuming that the numbers in the image "look" like the ones you trained on).
2. There are **neural network architectures** for this specific task, too. Have a look at object detection networks (e.g. YOLO, RFCN, etc. In this case you would have to train a new model).